# PIG setup throwing error

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig, bigdata

I was trying to install PIG v0.13.0 in my Fedora 20 system. After extracting the `tar.gz` contents, I did the `PATH` setup for `JAVA_HOME` and `PIG/bin`. Then I type the command `pig` in the console and this is what I got: Unable to understand what went wrong:

```
[root@localhost /]# pig
14/12/21 00:05:15 INFO pig.ExecTypeProvider: Trying ExecType : LOCAL
14/12/21 00:05:15 INFO pig.ExecTypeProvider: Trying ExecType : MAPREDUCE
14/12/21 00:05:15 INFO pig.ExecTypeProvider: Picked MAPREDUCE as the ExecType
2014-12-21 00:05:16,082 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Apache Pig version 0.13.0 (r1606446) compiled Jun 29 2014, 02:27:58
2014-12-21 00:05:16,083 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Logging error messages to: //pig_1419100516081.log
2014-12-21 00:05:16,130 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.impl.util.Utils - Default bootup file /root/.pigbootup not found
2014-12-21 00:05:16,765 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.job.tracker is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.address
2014-12-21 00:05:16,771 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2014-12-21 00:05:16,771 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine - Connecting to hadoop file system at: hdfs://localhost:8020
2014-12-21 00:05:16,780 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.used.genericoptionsparser is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.client.genericoptionsparser.used
2014-12-21 00:05:19,130 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.job.tracker is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.address
2014-12-21 00:05:19,130 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine - Connecting to map-reduce job tracker at: localhost:8021
2014-12-21 00:05:19,136 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
grunt> ls
2014-12-21 00:05:33,697 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2997: Encountered IOException. Call From localhost.localdomain/127.0.0.1 to localhost:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
Details at logfile: //pig_1419100516081.log
```

Please let me know why did the `ls` command in `grunt shell` throw the error?

Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you type `pig` in console, by default it will go to `MAPREDUCE` mode, for that you need access to a `Hadoop cluster and HDFS installation`. Mapreduce mode is the default mode in pig.
It looks like your hadoop cluster is not configured properly that is the reason you are getting the connection refunded error. Please follow up this link to solve this connect-refused problem.http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused.

As a workaround use `LOCAL` mode, this doesn't need hadoop installation.
In the console type `pig -x local` this will bring the grunt shell and type `ls` command.

**Local mode**

```
$ pig -x local
```

**Mapreduce mode**

```
$ pig 
(or)                 //try to connect HDFS
$ pig -x mapreduce
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got this one working. if I connect to the `pig mapreduce mode` the the `ls` command will change to `ls hdfs:/`. Hence changing the above command from `ls` to `ls hdfs:/` resolves my problem. But again, if I am connecting to the `local` mode then the `ls` command works fine.